# Graphics.Polygon code not working - what am I missing?

Tags: delphi, graphics, polygon, gdi+

My little code creates modern art to the full screen size Form canvas with different kind of shapes.
I can make ellipse, rectangle and line work but not the polycon. Can any one help me? (Version: Delphi community edition )

```
uses .... GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  graphics: TGPGraphics;
  SolidPen: TGPPen;
  SolidBrush : TGPBrush;
  x,y,x2,y2,x3,y3 : integer;

begin

graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);

SolidPen := TGPPen.Create(MakeColor(255, random(255), random(255), random(255)), random(4)+1);

SolidBrush := TGPSolidBrush.Create(MakeColor(255, random(255), random(255), random(255)));

SolidPen.SetStartCap(LineCapRound);
SolidPen.SetEndCap(LineCapRound);

//POLYCON, not working.------------------ 
// PROBLEM HERE: it's complaining:  'Oridinal type required' ,
// 'incompatible type: integer and TPoint'
x:= 150; y := 50; x2 := 50; y2 := 250;  x3 := 250; y3 := 250;
graphics.FillPolygon(SolidBrush, [Point(x, y), Point(x2, y2), Point(x3, y3)]);
graphics.DrawPolygon(SolidPen, [Point(x, y), Point(x2, y2), Point(x3, y3)]);
//--------------------------------------------

// ELLIPSE, ok
x := random(Form1.width); y := random(Form1.height); x2 := random(200); y2 := random(200);
graphics.FillEllipse(SolidBrush,x, y, x2, y2);
graphics.DrawEllipse(SolidPen,x, y, x2, y2);

// RECTANGLE, ok
x := random(Form1.width); y := random(Form1.height); x2 := random(200); y2 := random(200);
graphics.FillRectangle(SolidBrush, x, y, x2, y2);
graphics.DrawRectangle(SolidPen, x, y, x2, y2);

// LINE, ok
x := random(Form1.width); y := random(Form1.height); x2 := random(Form1.width); y2 := random(Form1.height);
graphics.DrawLine(SolidPen, x, y, x2, y2);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.Height := Screen.Height;
Form1.Width := Screen.Width;
end;
```

Comment: Your bigger problem is that your drawing won't survive a paint cycle.

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the points of the polygon correctly.

Looking at the two overloaded `DrawPolygon()` declarations:

```
function TGPGraphics.DrawPolygon(pen: TGPPen; points: PGPPointF; count: Integer): TStatus;
function TGPGraphics.DrawPolygon(pen: TGPPen; points: PGPPoint; count: Integer): TStatus;
```

you can see that the points are passed as a `PGPPointF` or `PGPPoint`. The definitions of these types are found in `Winapi.GDIPAPI` and there we see that the coordinates are either `single` or `integer`

Since you are using integer coordinates look at the definition of `PGPPoint` in Winapi.GDIPAPI

```
type
  PGPPoint = ^TGPPoint;
  TGPPoint = record
    X : Integer;
    Y : Integer;
  end;
  TPointDynArray = array of TGPPoint;

  function MakePoint(X, Y: Integer): TGPPoint; overload;
  {$EXTERNALSYM MakePoint}
```

So, declare a variable

```
ArrOfPoint: TPointDynArray;
```

and fill it with your points:

```
SetLength(ArrOfPoint, 3);
ArrOfPoint[0] := MakePoint(x, y);
ArrOfPoint[1] := MakePoint(x2, y2);
ArrOfPoint[2] := MakePoint(x3, y3);
```

Finally replace your call to e.g. `DrawPolygon()` with

```
graphics.DrawPolygon(SolidPen, PGPPoint(@ArrOfPoint[0]), 3);
```

meaning you pass the address of the first point as a `PGPPoint` type.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Tom. I was confused at first because with traditional graphics a polygon was so easy to make.

Comment: You are welcome. Now that you got it working, consider the comment by David Heffernan and move the code to the `OnPaint` event of your form or of whatever you want to paint it on.

Answer (score 0):

So, the corrected working code for the polygon is following (at the moment):

```
uses
... GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
graphics: TGPGraphics;
SolidPen: TGPPen;
SolidBrush : TGPBrush;

ArrOfPoint: TPointDynArray;
x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3 : integer;

begin

graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);

SolidPen := TGPPen.Create(MakeColor(255, random(255), random(255), random(255)), random(4)+1);
SolidBrush := TGPSolidBrush.Create(MakeColor(255, random(255), random(255), random(255)));

x := random(Form1.Width); y := random(Form1.Height);
x2 := random(Form1.Width); y2 := random(Form1.Height);
x3 := random(Form1.Width); y3 := random(Form1.Height);

SetLength(ArrOfPoint, 3);
ArrOfPoint[0] := MakePoint(x, y);
ArrOfPoint[1] := MakePoint(x2, y2);
ArrOfPoint[2] := MakePoint(x3, y3);

graphics.FillPolygon(SolidBrush,PGPPoint(@ArrOfPoint[0]), 3);
graphics.DrawPolygon(SolidPen, PGPPoint(@ArrOfPoint[0]), 3);

end;
```